# merge some data with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have some data like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'code': ['A', 'A','A' ,'B', 'B','B', 'C'],
                     'type' : ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd'],
                     'start': ['2017-1-1', '2018-5-5', '2017-5-21', '2017-6-6','2017-7-8','2017-8-9','2018-5-1'],
                    'end': ['2017-5-20', 'now', '2017-5-4', '2017-7-7','2017-8-8','now','now']})

╔═══╦══════╦══════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║   ║ code ║ type ║ start     ║ end       ║
╠═══╬══════╬══════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 0 ║ A    ║ a    ║ 2017-1-1  ║ 2017-5-20 ║
╠═══╬══════╬══════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 1 ║ A    ║ a    ║ 2018-5-5  ║ now       ║
╠═══╬══════╬══════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 2 ║ A    ║ b    ║ 2017-5-21 ║ 2017-5-4  ║
╠═══╬══════╬══════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 3 ║ B    ║ c    ║ 2017-6-6  ║ 2017-7-7  ║
╠═══╬══════╬══════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 4 ║ B    ║ c    ║ 2017-7-8  ║ 2017-8-8  ║
╠═══╬══════╬══════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 5 ║ B    ║ c    ║ 2017-8-9  ║ now       ║
╠═══╬══════╬══════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 6 ║ C    ║ d    ║ 2018-5-1  ║ now       ║
╚═══╩══════╩══════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

and I want to convert it as shown below using pandas:

```
╔═══╦══════╦══════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║   ║ code ║ type ║ start     ║ end       ║
╠═══╬══════╬══════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 0 ║ A    ║ a    ║ 2017-1-1  ║ 2017-5-20 ║
╠═══╬══════╬══════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 1 ║ A    ║ a    ║ 2018-5-5  ║ now       ║
╠═══╬══════╬══════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 2 ║ A    ║ b    ║ 2017-5-21 ║ 2017-5-4  ║
╠═══╬══════╬══════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 3 ║ B    ║ c    ║ 2017-6-6  ║ now       ║
╠═══╬══════╬══════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 4 ║ C    ║ d    ║ 2018-5-1  ║ now       ║
╚═══╩══════╩══════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

The data needs to be merged on *code* and *type* fields for which the *date* values form a continuous date range(like the dates [2017-6-6], [2017-7-7], [2017-7-8], [2017-8-8], [2017-8-9], *now* can be merged into [2017-6-6] to *now*).

If the *date*s are not continuous then they should not be grouped/merged and no changes to the start and end.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why would you choose to format your data like this D:  You were doing so well by providing the input dataframe :)

Comment: So you'd like to convert continuous time sequences to a single row?

Comment: How exactly do you want to convert your data? I cannot see from your example what is the intended transformation.

Comment: Why are rows 0 and 2 not combined?

Comment: i masked mistake in 0 and 2 and i changed it.

Comment: Can you update your desired output then?  If your rule holds the first two rows should now be combined

Comment: i updated all of them

Comment: @Tavakoli your updated output is not correct.  Why do you not group the first two rows together? They have the same code and type?

Comment: they aren't  sequential (continues) in date

Comment: You should really clarify that in your question.  But does sequential mean continuous months? I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
grp_helper = df.groupby(['code','type'])\
               .apply(lambda x: (pd.to_datetime(x['start']) - 
                                 pd.to_datetime(x['end'], errors='coerce').shift(1) 
                                 != pd.Timedelta(days=1)).cumsum()).values

df.groupby(['code','type',grp_helper])[['start','end']]\
  .agg({'start':'min','end':'max'}).reset_index().drop('level_2', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  code type      start        end
0    A    a   2017-1-1  2017-5-20
1    A    a   2018-5-5        now
2    A    b  2017-5-21   2017-5-4
3    B    c   2017-6-6        now
4    C    d   2018-5-1        now
```

Comment: Okay, we first create a group_helper array which basically groups the dataframe on 'code' and 'type' then shifts end column down, so we can subtract start minus end to see if there is exactly 1 day difference, if not one day then increment by one with cumsum.  If its on day don't increment keeping the same value as the previous row.  Hence, creating a group of records.